# Utilize single connections multiple times

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making a program that fetches app from APKmirror

So, I fetch the page using urllib3 and scrap it using Beautiful Soup

```
for a in ((BeautifulSoup((urlopen(Request(url="https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/twitter-inc/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read()), 'lxml')).find_all(["a"], class_="fontBlack", text=re.compile("^.*.release*"))):
    twver = ((a.string).split(' ')[1]).replace(".", "-")
    break
twurl = "".join(["https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/twitter-inc/twitter/twitter-", twver, "-release/"])

twpage1= "".join(["https://apkmirror.com", ((((BeautifulSoup((urlopen(Request(url=twurl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read()), 'lxml')).find(["span"], text="APK")).parent).find(["a"], class_="accent_color")['href'])])

twpage2= "".join(["https://apkmirror.com", ((BeautifulSoup((urlopen(Request(url=twpage1, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read()), 'lxml')).find(["a"], { 'class' : re.compile("accent_bg btn btn-flat downloadButton")})['href'])])

twdllink = "".join(["https://apkmirror.com", (((BeautifulSoup((urlopen(Request(url=twpage2, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read()), 'lxml')).find(rel="nofollow"))['href'])])
```

So, I request you to please tell how to use a single conenction to apkmirror server and use it to fetch different url everytime.

You can see the url changes everytime.

Or suggest me other ways to make it fast..

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'
}


def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = get_soup(r.content)
        links = (urljoin(url, x['href'])
                 for x in soup.select('a.fontBlack[href*=release]'))
        for link in links:
            # From here you can continue 
            # r = req.get(link) as you are using the same session currently
            print(link)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/twitter-inc/')
```

Comment: but the link is different every time, because I have to scrap webpage three times.
see here
https://i.imgur.com/Yf4N0wZ.png